# What happens between Payload deployment and the ISS docking

Tags: spacex, iss, falcon-9

When SpaceX is livestreaming their CRS missions they usually end up by separating the payload from the second stage with an altitude at about 200 km. But I am wondering how the payload gets up to the 400 km altitude where the ISS is located.

Comment: The orbit might be elliptical and the deployment might happen at periapsis

Comment: They make multiple adjustments using their Draco thrusters to adjust the orbit, step by step.